# Link mongoose schemas using ID's pushed to an array?

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm trying to link 2 of my mongoose schemas using the ID's assigned by mongoose (_id)
I have a users schema and a servers schema, every server should have 1 user as the owner but every user can have many servers. So I'm saving the req.user.id(from passportJS) in the server schema and there is an array in users schema where I want to push the ID's for servers when they are created. I haven't quite made it to using populate yet because I don't understand how to take the ID from the server that is about to be created and push it to the users server array

Here is my servers schema:

```
var mongoose = require ('mongoose');
var timestamps = require('mongoose-times');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ServerSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    imgurl: String,
    address: String,
    port: String,
    tags: Array,
    votifier    :{
        enabled: Boolean,
        address: String,
        port: String,
        pubKey: String
    },
    ownerID: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0}
});

ServerSchema.plugin(timestamps);


module.exports = mongoose.model('Server', ServerSchema);
```

Here's my users schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var timestamps = require('mongoose-times');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = Schema({
    local       :{
        username: {type: String, required: true},
        password: {type: String, required: true}
    },
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    imgId: String,
    servers: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Server'}]
});

userSchema.plugin(timestamps);

//methods
//gen hash
userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password, next){
    bcrypt.hash(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null, next);
    console.log(password + ': Password has generated hash');
};

userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.local.password, function(err, isMatch){
        if(err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

How can I take the _ID of a server that is being created and push it to the array in the User schema which I will findByID using the OwnerID in server schema?

Any help would be appreciated, also if this is the complete wrong way to do this sort of thing please let me know! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new server like that:

```
newServer = new ServerSchema(...);
```

Then save it:

```
newServer.save(callback);
```

The callback should be define to do whatever you want to do with the actual saved result. Lets say that you have a function updateUser that receive userId and serverId and it pushes the serverId to the User of that Id.
Then your callback should be something like...

```
callback = function(serverSaveErr, serverSavedDoc) {
  if (serverSaveErr) { handle errors ... }
  else { updateUser(userId, serverSavedDoc._id }
}
```